# Setup Activity object security

Tags: lightning, security, activity, activity-settings

I have a problem while setuping security for Activity object.
The problem is standart behaviour of OWD setting for Activity. Even If i set private records are shared to people who has Read access to parent records (WhatId or WhoId).

My requirement is to restrict visibility of records using restriction rules but it's not possible because i can't get parent's fields using dot notation (like WhoId.Name for example) because parent's fields are accessible only as Ids.

How can i restrict access to Activity records in other way ?